# Add constraint if not exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, alter-table

I want to add the 'check' constraint to some table, but firstly I have to check if that constraint exists. I have some error in my SQL script. What is the corret way to do it ?

```
   ALTER TABLE public.ELEMENTS ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS elements_check CHECK ((t1_id IS NOT NULL) OR (t2_id IS NOT NULL));
```

Comment: Avoid using `IF NOT EXISTS`. It's error prone and your script will produce unexpected results if the constraint already existed with a different definition.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "exists"

Comment: Its a weird inconsistency that it doesnt exist. :

Answer (score 3):

According to the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) :

1. `ALTER TABLE ... DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS` do exist
2. `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS` doesn't exist

so you have to execute 1. before 2. :

```
ALTER TABLE public.ELEMENTS DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS elements_check ;

ALTER TABLE public.ELEMENTS ADD CONSTRAINT elements_check CHECK ((t1_id IS NOT NULL) OR (t2_id IS NOT NULL));
```

Comment: then I have   
 ALTER TABLE public.ELEMENT ADD constraint elements_check CHECK ((t1_id IS NOT NULL) OR (t2_id IS NOT NULL)) if not exists;

And I have  SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "if"

Comment: You misunderstood my initial answer. See the update answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use this statement to check wherever a Primary Key exists or not in SQL Server.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'PrimaryKeyName') AND type in (N'PK') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'TableName')
```